# adding a new input channel in keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to fine-tune VGG19 in keras using the functional APIs. First, I load the pre-trained model by `base_model = VGG19(weights='imagenet')`. Now, I want to add a 4th channel to the input (the pre-trained models has 3 channels i.e. R, G, and B). Could someone let me know how I can add the 4th channel with random initialization?